# jQuery dynamic jcarsoul make it as autorun

Tags: jquery

I am using this the [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_ajax_php.html) jQuery plugin.

How to change the click mode to automatically run mode?

The present scenario: when you click NEXT it shows the next three images. 
When you click BACK it shows the previous three images.

I want to change this scenario to:

When it loads, the plugin should start running (image). I also need the NEXT and BACK button. When the user click the back button, then it should show the previous three images and run the image towards back.

Is it possible?

Comment: This didn't need to be community wiki, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at some of the [other examples](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Examples), you'll notice: [Carousel with autoscrolling](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Uncomment the following option if you want items
// which are outside the visible range to be removed
// from the DOM.
// Useful for carousels with MANY items.
auto: 1,
// wrap: 'last',
wrap: 'circular',
// easing: 'BounceEaseOut',
// vertical: true,
animation: 2500,
visible: 3,
speed:1000 ,
wrap: 'circular',

// itemVisibleOutCallback: {onAfterAnimation: function(carousel, item, i, state, evt) { carousel.remove(i); }},
itemLoadCallback: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback
```

This fixed my problems.